# How to make sure that any new tag added to the XML document will be loaded to the browser

Tags: ajax

I am using the below code to loop through  an XML document in order to get the "food" elements. I want to make sure that when an XML element is added it will be shown in the browser automaticaly as a list item.

```
    var myNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('food')

    for (var i=0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) {
    var output = '<ul>';
    var food = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('food')[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to figure it out through the following approach:

```
    var foodList = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('food')

    for (var i=0; i < foodList.length; i++) {
    var output = '<ul>';
    var food = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('food')[i];
```